# Android: How to send a message back to my Activity from a Notification, without opening Activity?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In Android, I have a notification and I want to send a message back to the activity (and use the message to control my app). What is the simplest method to do that with `PendingIntent`? Is `getBroadcast` the appropriate way? `getActivity` opens the activity and I don't want to open it, but only tell it to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background service to receive message sending by `PendingIntent.getService` [this](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) is the official guide about creating a background service

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

In 3 steps

```
Define events:
public class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }

Prepare subscribers:
eventBus.register(this);
public void onEvent(AnyEventType event) {/* Do something */};

Post events:
eventBus.post(event);
```

or you can use [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)